# Postman integration with Jenkins, table not shown properly

Tags: jenkins, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have integrated a Postman sample with Jenkins and the same works properly in the newman cmd line, but not in Jenkins.

[[image: Newman CMD[1]]

[image: Jenkins Execution]

Answer (score 1):

You can add different [options](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#cli-reporter-options) to the command, to change the output.

This maybe useful to you:

```
--disable-unicode
```

> Specify whether or not to force the unicode disable option. When supplied, all symbols in the output will be replaced by their plain text equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

In your Jenkins job build section type

```
newman run --disable-unicode <postman_collection_name>
```